# Python http post a file using request library

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

I have to post a file along with some data to to api.
Here is the python code i wrote for testing:

```
fl={'payload' : open('C:/data/log2.txt')}
params = {
        'topic':'pos',
        'store':storeID,
         }

r = requests.post(url,files=fl,data=params)

print r.status
print r.text
```

But i always get a message saying, **"file is not in correct format"**

I tested the api with POSTMAN (chrome extension to test rest API) and it seems to work fine with postman i get a success response and the file is sent, here is a snapshot.

[image: api test using postman]

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you are getting?

Comment: I don't get a error, i just get a response from the server saying that "file is not in correct format".

Comment: That sounds like maybe your log file isn't formatted correctly... your code is probably good. In your question you reference two different files, `amazonlog.log` and `log2.txt`. Make sure that the file in your code is sent with the same name and has the same contents as `amazonlog.log`. Maybe you need a `.log` extension...?

Comment: the server accepts any text file, i tested it with log2.txt using postman and server accepts it. I can't check it right now but i will check it as soon as i get back to work.

Comment: I tried with same file names and content. While it was working with postman it did not work with python requests. I suspect that there is a bug related to encoding in python requests module. For the same file that was uploaded using postman, i get a response in python as: {"status": "Error", "message": "{'payload': [u'File type is not supported']}"}

Comment: It's very possible that what you're uploading to requires the parameters to be ordered exactly as you already have them ordered in POSTMAN. If that's the case, requests currently doesn't support interleaving files and text parameters. Also if order is important, you should be aware that python dictionaries do not preserver ordering. To do so, use a list of tuples, e.g., `[('topic', 'pos'), ('store', '...'), ('payload', open('file.txt'))]`

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  ...
}
```

Try adding `'rb'` to your open statement so that you are uploading binary data.

Change

`fl={'payload' : open('C:/data/log2.txt')}`

to

`fl={'payload' : open('C:/data/log2.txt', 'rb')}`